# What is the equivalent of C++ std::unordered_map<char, int> in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, c++, hashmap, unordered-map

So I am trying to map the number of times a char appears in a string. I know that in C++ it would be.

```
std::string str = "AbBAaaaa";
std::unordered_map<char, int> myMap;

for(auto i = str)
{
   ++mymap[i];
}
```

How would I translate this to JavaScript?

Answer (score 5):

I would `reduce` the string into an object indexed by character. The function passed to `reduce` is called for each element in the input, where the first argument (the `a`) is the accumulator, which is either the initial value (`{}` here) or what the last iteration returned. The second argument (the `char`) is the current character being iterated over.

```js
const str = "AbBAaaaa";
const charCounts = Array.prototype.reduce.call(str, (a, char) => {
  a[char] = (a[char] || 0) + 1;
  return a;
}, {});
console.log(charCounts);
```

You could also use

```
const charCounts = [...str].reduce((a, char) => // ...
```

which is shorter and probably a bit easier to understand at a glance, but unnecessarily creates an intermediate array from the `str`.

The imperative version of this, with a `for` loop, would look like:

```js
const str = "AbBAaaaa";
const charCounts = {};
for (let i = 0; i < str.length; i++) {
  const char = str[i];
  charCounts[char] = (charCounts[char] || 0) + 1;
}
console.log(charCounts);
```

Comment: What does charCounts[char] || 0 do?

Comment: @TomOconnor Defaults to `0` if `charCounts[char]` is `undefined`.

Answer (score 0):

Javascript already has map and you can achieve same result of your C++ app as shown in this snippet

```js
function charOccurances(str) {
  var myMap = {};
  if(str.length!==0){
    for (let i = 0; i < str.length; i++) {
      myMap[str[i]] = (myMap[str[i]] || 0) + 1;
    }
  }
  return myMap;
}

const str = "AbABaaaa";
console.log(charOccurances(str));
```